# Grails one to many with limit on returned children

Tags: grails, grails-orm, one-to-many

so i have two classes which have a one to many connection between them...

```
class A {
   static hasMany = {bs: B}
}

class B {
   String name
}
```

now i create an object A and add 100 B objects to its list...

now when i call A.get(1) and access the Bs it will load all 100 objects into memory. I would like to limit this to 10 B objects and have another method return the next 10 and so on.

Is there an easy way of doing this? So far the only way i see of doing this is never directly access the B objects and have a helper method that gets them.

so what i am looking for is paging for the one to many association

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the [`batchSize`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/batchSize.html) for your `hasMany` in the `mappings` block.

```
static mapping = {
    bs batchSize: 10
}
```

Comment: and then how would i get the next 10?

Comment: actually with all the batch size does is load them in packs... so normally if you dont specify a join in gorm for this association grails would do in my example 101 queries... 1 query for A and 100 queries to get each B... now with batch size it would only do 11... 1 for A and 10 for each 10 Bs...

but my question was that i only wanted to load the first 10 Bs and when i click some other button then it would page to the next 10 Bs... what i am looking for is paging for the one to many association

Comment: @ChristopherRivera as far as I know what you try to do is impossible, at least with GORM. Also the `batchSize` doesn't actually work like that, the official documentation is wrong - if you set `bs batchSize: 10` on the parent, then what it will actually do is fetch `all the bs of 10 parents, at the same time`. So if you have one A with 10 bs and one A with 200 bs, the batchSize will cause all of them to be loaded in a single query. With Sql logging it will look like this: `select ... from B where a_id in (?, ?)`

Comment: lol this is from like 10 years ago - is grails still a thing?

Answer (score -1):

You could use the standard params properties for this, these are often used to get paged resultset. Check out the list methods on how to work with them

- params.min ~ The minimum number to list
- params.max ~ The maximum number to list
- params.offset ~ The offset from the first result to list from

See more over here:
http://grails.org/doc/2.2.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/list.html

Comment: This is for when accessing Bs directly through `B.list()`. The question was how to achieve this when accessing Bs via A, i.e. `someA.bs`